# Is material produced for a course considered property of the department?

Tags: legal-issues, course-design, academic-freedom, netherlands

I was asked last year to set up a completely new course, far from my expertise (say, you work on differential equations but they ask you to teach general relativity). The department did not give me much space/resources to do so but anyway I did it very successfully and on a very short notice (based on student's evaluations etc.)

- Does the department have the right to take all the material I developed and give it to a new instructor, say next year?
- Do they need my agreement and do I have the right to refuse to do so?
- Can I take the entire developed course in, for example, a new institution in case I move away? Or the department can claim that it was part of my paid job so it is theirs?

On an ethical level I find it unfair that I had to put an insane amount of work only for the department to come and claim my work and give it "for free" to a new instructor. But I am not sure if legally I can do anything about that.

For what is worth, I am in an academic institution in the Netherlands. I am assistant professor (UD) and, according to the rules (at least in my institution) my job is not to develop new courses, but only to deliver/maintain existing courses in the curriculum.

Comment: What is  your role, are you faculty?

Comment: What does your employment contract say about this? Assuming you were compensated (by a salary), I don't see anything unfair or unethical here.

Comment: @Roland Nothing. Actually, according to the rules, it is not even my job (as assistant professor) to create new courses. But I did (without extra compensation).

Comment: @PsySp Usually there are some general clauses about work outside your core duties and intellectual property.

Comment: If your contract doesn't specify who owns the copyright in those teaching materials, then the ownership will be decided by the default position set out in the intellectual property law of your country.  I've seen an English translation of the Auteurswet (particularly article 7 thereof), and I think you should prepare to be disappointed.

Comment: @DanielHatton Thanks! I have been disappointed so many times, one more won't make any difference.

Answer (score 1):

This is a question that really depends on local custom and policy.  At my institution, there's a clear policy that I own the copyright to materials that I produce for my teaching unless those materials were produced with extra institutional support (e.g. I'm paid extra to develop the course or the institution provides an instructional designer to help in developing a course.)

I'm aware that at many other institutions in the US, instructional content (course syllabi, lecture slides, assignments, etc.) are considered to be work for hire and owned by the institution.  This is very helpful when a course is frequently taught by contingent faculty.

Comment: Thanks. As I have updated on my question, it is not even part of my job to create new content (this is reserved for Assoc. Profs and higher). I did that without getting compensated. I wonder if in any case the department can act as they own whatever material I have developed.

Answer (score 1):

I will limit my answer to what is customary among academics.  If you want to know what is legal, read your employment contract.  The contract is what is enforceable.

- Does the department have the right to take all the material I developed and give it to a new instructor, say next year?

Academics feel the instructor owns the course design they made, so no.

- Do they need my agreement and do I have the right to refuse to do so?

Yes they need your agreement, but the ethical and customary thing to do would be to agree.

- Can I take the entire developed course in, for example, a new institution in case I move away? Or the department can claim that it was part of my paid job so it is theirs?

Yes, you can take the course materials with you to use with a new employer.

Answer (score 0):

I can't address the legal questions you ask (nor do people usually on this site).

Are they claiming such rights, or are you just worried that they might?

My experience in the United States with material I've developed is that I'm delighted when anyone wants to use it. I make it available to my colleagues at my school and elsewhere, and can take it with me to use and revise if I change jobs.

When I have turned such material into a textbook I have owned the rights and royalties (although I always arranged not to collect royalties when I assigned my book to my students).

Comment: I have absolutely no problem with _colleagues_ asking for my material. But I am wondering if the _department_ can simply hand them over to a new teaching stuff (the question is not theoretical, this is consistent with their inner workings here). Basically they said to me "develop the course till the expert comes and s/he can pick it up from there". Besides, I might be leaving so I wonder what happens to the material developed.

Comment: That suggests that they told you in advance that they wanted to continue using the material even if you weren't there. If you accepted that arrangement then I guess that was part of what you were paid for. I suspect you could still use/revise the material elsewhere in the future. If you're on reasonable terms with the department chair, perhaps just ask. We can't do more to help you from this distance.

Comment: Well, I did not agree to do other people's job! I do not know what they had in mind. If the new person asks politely then that is one thing. But I wonder if the department can see whatever I have developed as their property and can do whatever they please with it.